# Build one object from foreach loop

Tags: php, json, foreach

I want to take an array I build from a result set, encode it and then put it into a single object. My problem is I am making a lot of objects, but I want all my data to be in one object. The problem is that I echo out multiple objects from my json encode on my foreach loop. How would I take all that data I get out of that foreach loop and put it into one object? Any help is appreciated. Below is my code. Basically, what I need is this.

```
{"item1":"itemdata","category":"mycategory"}
```

but all in one object. I don't want multiple `{} {} {}`

```
$counter = 0;
$itemID = '';
foreach ($resultsTwo as $result) {
        if ($counter >= 0 && $itemID != $result['item_id']) {
                $description = $result['item_desc'];
                $ID = substr($result['item_id'], 3, 6);
                if ($result['bidder'] == 9999999999) {
                        $bid = $result['amount_bid'] + $result['min_bid_increment'];
                } else {
                        $bid = preg_replace('~\.0+$~','',$result['amount_bid']);
                }
                //echo $ID . ' ' . $bid . '<br />';
                $build['bid'] = $bid;
                $build['id'] = $ID;
                $build['item_desc'] = $description;         
        }
        $itemID = $result['item_id'];
        $counter++;

        echo json_encode($build);
}
```

Comment: Do you not just want an array of the `$build` objects?

Comment: I have an array every time I loop through a row. I want to take all those arrays and convert them into one object.

Comment: is this how you want {"item1":"itemdata","category":"mycategory", "item1":"itemdata2","category":"mycategory2"}

Comment: yes, that is how I want it to be.

Comment: one more this are you going to decode that? if so it's will automatically override previous keys such as   item1, category

Comment: Yeah I am decoding it through ajax. The plan was to decode it through a loop and run checks to see if its the same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array to hold the smaller arrays before your loop.

```
$fullData = array();
```

Then, inside your loop after you finish your build array add the build array to the fullData array.

```
$fullData[] = $build;
```

remove your current json_encode() and then, outside the loop.

```
echo json_encode($fullData);
```

This is what it would be changed to:

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
$itemID = '';

$fullData = array();

foreach ($resultsTwo as $result) {
    if ($counter >= 0 && $itemID != $result['item_id']) {
        $description = $result['item_desc'];
        $ID = substr($result['item_id'], 3, 6);
        if ($result['bidder'] == 9999999999) {
            $bid = $result['amount_bid'] + $result['min_bid_increment'];
        } else {
            $bid = preg_replace('~\.0+$~','',$result['amount_bid']);
        }
        //echo $ID . ' ' . $bid . '<br />';
        $build['bid'] = $bid;
        $build['id'] = $ID;
        $build['item_desc'] = $description;         
    }
    $itemID = $result['item_id'];
    $counter++;

    $fullData[] = $build;

}
echo json_encode($fullData);
?>
```

Comment: I don't necessarily need it inside an array, just all in one object {}.

Comment: When you encode the fullData array, it creates only one JSON object with all of your data inside of it.

Comment: You are right. My ajax pulls in the array even though there are multiple objects inside it. I thought I could have only one object it would accept.

Comment: Isn't one JSON object {}? Not multiple inside an array like you have built?

Comment: Essentially, you are outputting a multidimensional object (array). If you really wanted to put everything into only one object, you would have to rename all of the keys on the server side when you are adding to the array. However, you would need to rewrite your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$counter = 0;
$itemID = '';
foreach ($resultsTwo as $result) {
        if ($counter >= 0 && $itemID != $result['item_id']) {
                $description = $result['item_desc'];
                $ID = substr($result['item_id'], 3, 6);
                if ($result['bidder'] == 9999999999) {
                        $bid = $result['amount_bid'] + $result['min_bid_increment'];
                } else {
                        $bid = preg_replace('~\.0+$~','',$result['amount_bid']);
                }
                //echo $ID . ' ' . $bid . '<br />';
                $build['bid'] = $bid;
                $build['id'] = $ID;
                $build['item_desc'] = $description;         
        }
        $itemID = $result['item_id'];
        $counter++;

        echo json_encode($build);
}
```

To

```
$counter = 0;
$itemID = '';
foreach ($resultsTwo as $result) {
        if ($counter >= 0 && $itemID != $result['item_id']) {
                $description = $result['item_desc'];
                $ID = substr($result['item_id'], 3, 6);
                if ($result['bidder'] == 9999999999) {
                        $bid = $result['amount_bid'] + $result['min_bid_increment'];
                } else {
                        $bid = preg_replace('~\.0+$~','',$result['amount_bid']);
                }
                //echo $ID . ' ' . $bid . '<br />';


                 $build[] = array('bid'=>$bid,'id'=>$ID,'item_desc'=>$description);  


        }
        $itemID = $result['item_id'];
        $counter++;
         }




        echo json_encode($build);
```

Comment: Are you building an array inside an array on the line that starts with build[]?

Comment: The one you used will override previous array

Comment: I am still getting multiple objects within objects when I echo out the encode.

Comment: I'm not sure how you designed the application, but I guess this is how  it should be to prevent overriding arrays.